# Excel: How do I change the Cell Content based on the Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following criteria for my excel. 
90%, 70% & 30% hike in salaries are being categorized for all the available cadres. Eg. Manager, Assistant Manager, Senior Engineer, Jr. Engineer.
The cadre should be promoted if the salaries are hiked by >=70% (i.e. for 70% and 90% hikers) 
E.g.
1. Mr. X - Senior Engineer should be promoted to Asst. Mgr for 90% hike in salary
2. Mr. Y - Assistant Manager should be retained as Asst. Mgr for 30% hike in salary.

How do I write a formula for this?

Hope I am clear with my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly your question.

But there is the if statement:

ex: =IF(A2 >=70,"Promoted","Not promoted")

Answer (score 0):

May be OP wants to get the position to which cadre is promoted rather than identify promotion status.

In that case following setup would help.

If you have 
Current Positions in column A
Hike % in column B

Setup a list of positions in column 'F' according to hierarchy in increasing order. Eg. F2 = Jr. Engg, F3 = Sr. Engg and so on.
Use exact same names as in existing position

Label column C as 'New Position' and in cell C2 enter formula

```
=IF(B2>=70%,INDEX($F$2:$F$5,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$5,0)+1,1),A2)
```